# sql query to update datetime field based on currentdate + value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two fields in a table, one varchar field which is saving values such as 3, 4, 11 or NULL which translates to 3, 4 or 11 years.

Recently I introduced new column in the same table of type date where I'm saving dates and which will eventually replace the previous field.

These are the actual columns:

[image]

So for the new LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate field I want to do GETDATE() + the value in the LeaseRemainingFirstBreak field if its not null.

Comment: Did you use [DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)?

Comment: Something like this DATEADD(yyyy,LeaseRemainingFirstBreak,GETDATE()) I assume?

Comment: Yes, you need to handle NULL for second parameter

Comment: Can you give me an example please how to handle NULL as well Thanks

Comment: try this `SELECT DATEADD(yyyy, COALESCE(LeaseRemainingFirstBreak,0), GETDATE())`

Comment: Do you need to ignore NULL fields or do you need to populate CurrentDate if it is null? Previous one does latter

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE [tablename]
SET [LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate] = dateadd(year, [LeaseRemainingFirstBreak], convert(date, getDate()) 
where [LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate] is not null`

The convert ensures that the format matches the date format shown in the other values in that field.

Comment: why do you need `CONVERT` for `GETDATE()`?

Comment: Otherwise it would return the hours/minutes/seconds - just matching the naming convention of the existing dates shown in the example.

Comment: Getting this error Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: The LeaseRemainingFirstBreak field needs to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

With the ambiguity in the question,

If yo want to ignore NULLs and update other rows,

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate = DATEADD(yyyy, CONVERT(INT, LeaseRemainingFirstBreak), GETDATE())
WHERE LeaseRemainingFirstBreak IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to consider current date for those with NULL values,

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate = DATEADD(yyyy, CONVERT(INT, COALESCE(LeaseRemainingFirstBreak,0)), GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Via Using **`DATEADD`** Function.

**Eample:**

```
Create table Test (LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate int ,LeaseRemainingFirstBreak datetime )
Go

Insert into Test (LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate  ,LeaseRemainingFirstBreak  )
Values  (2, null),
        (12, null),
        (22, null),
        (Null, null),
        (Null, null)
GO

Select * from Test
```

The Result:

[image]

```
Update Test
Set LeaseRemainingFirstBreak =  DATEADD(YEAR,LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate,getDate())
where LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate is Not NULL
```

The **Result**:

[image]

Note: I excluded the rows that have NULL while updating via using

```
  where LeaseRemainingFirstBreakDate is Not NULL
```

IF you wanna update the other null rows, handel Null via using

`ISNULL` or `COLLASE` functions.